# ServiceStack Forbidden (403) error returned as Internal Server Error (500) when using server-side async

Tags: jquery, http, servicestack

I have a simple request to delete an entity. In the implementation I throw a HttpError with the 403 (Forbidden) status when it can't be deleted. If I make the server implementation async, with JQuery I get a HTTP 500 (Internal Server Response) instead of the expected 403 response I was getting with the synchronous implementation.

```
public object Delete(DeleteEntity request)
{
    ...
    throw new HttpError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Cannot delete entity because...");
}
```

With this synchronous implementation I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.07 Win32NT/.NET
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.07 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcU2t5RHJpdmVcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFRlY2hNRFxDb2RlXEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uc1xDQUNcQ0FDLldlYkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uXGFwaVxBcmVhc1wx?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 03 Feb 2014 10:28:14 GMT
Content-Length: 283
```

The same service method but asynchronous:

```
public async Task<object> Delete(DeleteEntity request)
{
    ...
    throw new HttpError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Cannot delete entity because...");
}
```

will generate a different response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcU2t5RHJpdmVcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFRlY2hNRFxDb2RlXEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uc1xDQUNcQ0FDLldlYkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uXGFwaVxBcmVhc1wx?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 03 Feb 2014 10:16:12 GMT
Content-Length: 5978
```

Is this by design or a bug? Also as a side question, is there a way to retrieve the exception message using JQuery (without having to parse the jqxhr.responseText string and pull out the title from the html document)?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with error handling in ASP.NET / IIS, see:

- [How to send a Status Code 500 in ASP.Net and still write to the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4495961/85785)
- http://forums.asp.net/p/1946691/5549935.aspx

You can add the suggested workaround in ServiceStack by registering a Pre-Request filter, e.g:

```
this.PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) => {
    var aspRes = httpRes.OriginalResponse as System.Web.HttpResponseBase;
    if (aspRes != null) 
        aspRes.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I still get a 500 when throwing a 403 when using async. TrySkipIisCustomErrors is already true.

Comment: @GuyGodin can you post the raw HTTP Response (using WebInspector or Fiddler) so we can see if this error response is being generated ServiceStack or ASP.NET?

Comment: @GuyGodin ok cool, should be fixed in [v4.09 just released](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes). Can you retry after updating NuGet.