# AngularJS & Ajax post - how to get ajax error (instead of success) callback to fire

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I'm kind of new to ajax so please excuse my ignorance.

In AngularJs, I make an ajax post like so:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:65337/api/Account/Register",
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + $scope.authToken);
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                },
                datatype: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(postObj)
            }).error(function (data, status, error) {
                $scope.$emit('MESSAGE', data.Message, data.IsError);
            }).success(function (xmlHttpRequest, status, error) {
                // this callback fires even on server error code 500
            })
```

and I am **trying to get the above error callback to fire when I encounter an internal error** on my server, when server encounters an error, I send the following response:

```
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        ErrorTModel data = new ErrorTModel(msg, IsError);

        response.Content = new StringContent(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data,
            Formatting.Indented,
            new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json"
            );

        return response;
```

I've read everything I can find on google regarding this matter so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: strongly suggest not mixing jQuery ajax api with angular. Youu really only want to ever have to use jQuery inside angular app for things that angular doesn't support

Comment: You have to throw HTTP error code.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495961/how-to-send-a-status-code-500-in-asp-net-and-still-write-to-the-response

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the heads up, after some research, are you referring to $http instead of $ajax ?

Comment: @OverMars yes. When you use code outside of angular to do things that modify scope you have to notify angular each time. Harder to test and no point doing it when angular has facilities already in place

Comment: Beginging refactoring, thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```

create and return the following:

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new Exception("Test"));
```

and the .error callback of any $Ajax or $http method will fire.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the c# code. The easiest way to get the error callback to fire (for testing purposes) is to throw an exception in your c# code:

```
throw new Exception();
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave out a required key/value pair from data that is being posted, referring to `postObj` on line 9 of the javascript. I would assume that all or part of it is required when posting to an account registration endpoint.

Comment: Could you post some example code of what you mean? What data should OP not include in his/her `POST`? How can OP trigger the `error` callback? Answering with explanatory code, in this case, helps to learn where a mistake was made.

Comment: I'm referring to the `postObj` variable on line 9, which is the data being posted to `/api/Account/Register`. I'm not sure what that object contains, but I assume it has a name, password, or some other data used to register an account, and I would think that at least one key/value pair in the object is required. So leave one out.

Comment: That would either reject my call to the server or throw an error server side, I'm trying to reverse the flow. When an error is thrown server side, I want to relay that message to the user.

Comment: Maybe what Wayne Ellery suggested, `throw new Exception();` in the c# code. We use Django Rest Framework/angular at work, and raising an exception in a DRF view set triggers the failure callback (we generally use angular's `$resource`), that's why I suggested what I did. Works in my case. :-) Good luck

Comment: Thnx @RachelHathaway, your suggestion helped me find what I needed.